# Does the Laplace Transform time shift property hold for t<0?

Tags: laplace-transform

Here's the example that caused the question

$$ y(t) = x_1(t-3) \circledast x_2(-t+2) \quad x_1(t) = e^{-4t}u(t) \quad x_2(t) = e^{-2t}u(t)$$

For $x_1$, the $t-3$ factor can be adjusted to be (time shifting)
$$ e^{-3s} \mathcal{L}\{ x_1(t)\} $$

but, for $x_2$, can the $-t+2$ be changed to 
$$ e^{2s} \mathcal{L}\{ x_2(t)\} $$